# Data conversion or data mapping error HY000 in multi row concatenation in sub select in view

Tags: sql, db2, db2-400

I have a sub-select as part of a view that generates a concatenated list of attributes from sub table. When doing a select from the view the data displays fine, but if it do a select in the concatenated list field I sometimes get the error Select or omit error on field.

AS400: V7R1M0

Main enitity:

```
MSGOCCID : CHAR 20  
other fields.....
```

The detail entity fields (MSDPF):

```
MSGOCCID : CHAR 20
OCC      : Integer 4
FIELDVAL : VARCHAR 128
```

I got the code for the sub select from StackOverflow and modified it for my situation. (I have also tried the recursive select but it very slow. The XMLSERIALIZE route is executable.)

To try and solve the problem it have added and removed REPLACE,COALESCE and TRIM of the value. I have added CCSID 1208 to the cast, changed the CHAR cast to VARCHAR... not change. (I have change CCSID 1208 to CCSID 37 at one stage to see if that will not solve it.)

If I run the select:

```
select MSGOCCID, COALESCE(DETLIST,' ') 
from WBVIEW MSGP 
where 1=1
```

If returns all the rows with not errors.

Sample output:

> ```
> MSGOCCID: 2019020443165590   
> MSGDLIST: 14620, 1, C20180914023575582, 4179792C, C20180914023575582, 4179792C, WIPSTOCK, REMOVE, ROU07561
> ```

But if I use:

```
select MSGOCCID, COALESCE(DETLIST,' ') 
from WBVIEW MSGP where 1=1 and DETLIST like '%4179792C%'
```

It fails with on the IBM backend:

> Data conversion or data mapping error.
>   Select or omit error on field MapXmlData(Cast(Concat(',
>   ',Strip(Replace(Cast(P6MSDPF_4.FIELDVAL AS VarChar(128) CCSID
>   1208),'-'),   Both,' ')) AS VarChar(260) CCSID 1208)) member
>   COMMSWKBL1.              Select/omit error on member COMMSWKBL1.

Short version of the view:

```
CREATE VIEW WBVIEW ( 
    MSGOCCID , 
    DETLIST ) 
    AS 
    (SELECT MSG.MSGOCCID,  
FROM P6DEVCDB00.P6MSGPF MSG 
     LEFT OUTER JOIN LATERAL
           (SELECT XMLSERIALIZE(XMLAGG(XMLTEXT(CONCAT(', ',TRIM(REPLACE(REPLACE(REPLACE(FIELDVAL,',','-'),'>','-'),'<','-'))))) AS VARCHAR(4096) CCSID 1208) AS DETLIST  
        FROM MSDPF MSGDET  
        WHERE COALESCE(MSGDET.MSGOCCID,' ') != ' ' and 
                  MSG.MSGOCCID = MSGDET.MSGOCCID AND 
                  MSGDET.FIELDVAL != ''
        GROUP BY MSGDET.MSGOCCID)MSGDLIST ON 1=1);
```

Character concatenation should not be a problem (except if it gets confused somewhere with the CCSIDs). I replace the <>, form the detail for in case that may interfere with xml functions... I have catered for Null and '' values ....

I have search lots of threads on lots of different sites and have run out of ideas.
Any suggestions will be appreciated.

Comment: Please edit your question to add the exact version (and fixpack) of your Db2 client software, and which operating-system and tool submits the SQL.

Comment: You write that it fails, but HY000 is a warning (not an error).  Is there a subcode along with the SQLCODE (e.g. +802 with error type value 1 to 12 ) per the description at https://www.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/en/ssw_ibm_i_74/rzala/rzalaml.htm

Comment: I'm going to mention that attempting a `LIKE` on the concatenated field (on most text fields, but _especially_ on this one, with how much you're doing to it) is going to perform **terribly**.  You would be far better off doing something like finding which `MSGOCCID`s have the relevant tag (probably by writing a [table valued function](https://www.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/en/ssw_ibm_i_71/db2/rbafzcftb.htm)) and then get the list based on that.  Also, you shouldn't need `COALESCE(MSGDET.MSGOCCID,' ') != ' '`, given null comparison rules.

Comment: 1. I did add AS400: V7R1M0 to the question. What more do you need? I am accessing the view via an SQLblockfetch function using odbc to connect to the DB. Even if I use IBM Data studio I get the error and no data is returned.

Comment: 2. The HY000 is the only code on the green screen in the joblog and returned on the ODBC error window. No other error code gets returned to be referenced.

Comment: 3.1 The view is for a trouble shooting workbench where the client wants to search on the main fields as well as on the detail. The detail is a breakdown of at message fields that may contain detail or not depending on the type of communication message. The string may not always be there depending on encoding/decoding situations but the detail should be there 95% of the time. the client wants to be able to search on anything without always known the exact numbers or string or word they are looking for. That is why the like is needed.

Comment: 3.2 I added the COALESCE because one or two of the sites it searched said that there may be null data in the key field that that person was using. It was one of the many options it tread in the the process of identifying the problem.

Comment: What is `COMMSWKBL1`? can you provide the definition of the associated file? is it DDS or DDL?

Comment: COMMSKBL1 ~ WBVIEW. COMMSKBL1 Is the actual implementation name of the full view. WBVIEW is the reduced version of the original view I made to make the question shorter and easier to ask and understand.

Comment: The entities (P6MSGPF,MSDPF) are DDS but the view(s) COMMSKBL1 ~ WBVIEW are SQL generate (DDL).

Answer (score 0):

I'm just guessing a quick comment answer here.  Those left outer joins can introduce nulls into the mix you can simply coalesce them in the where clause ...

select MSGOCCID, COALESCE(DETLIST,' ') 
from WBVIEW MSGP where 
coalesce(DETLIST,' ') like '%4179792C%'

IRL I would use locate because it just feels faster when it runs.

select MSGOCCID, COALESCE(DETLIST,' ') 
from WBVIEW MSGP where 
locate('4179792C' ,coalesce(DETLIST,' ')) <> 0

Comment: I have tested LOCATE vs LIKE and I get the error faster with LIKE as with LOCATE. (I did 3 test.)

Answer (score 0):

HY000 is a CLI (ODBC) General error, the explaination in the IBM documentation is:

> An error occurred for which there is no specific SQLSTATE and for which no implementation defined SQLSTATE is defined. The error message returned by SQLError in the argument szErrorMsg describes the error and its cause.

Since this is probably not something you are coding by hand, you probably do not have the opportunity to issue SQLError, but I suspect that the message you quoted in your question is the result of some internal process retrieving that error. so the problem should be:

> Data conversion or data mapping error.
>
> Select or omit error on field MapXmlData(Cast(Concat(',
> ',Strip(Replace(Cast(P6MSDPF_4.FIELDVAL AS VarChar(128) CCSID 1208),'-'), Both,' ')) AS VarChar(260) CCSID 1208)) member COMMSWKBL1. Select/omit error on member COMMSWKBL1.

I don't know your files, but I am guessing that there is bad data in the file and that COMMSWKBL1 is a `select logical` that is accessed to process the selection when you add the `DETLIST like '%4179792C%'` to your query. Your task is to find out which file is associated with member COMMSWKBL1, and see if you can determine why a Select or omit error would be occurring on that file.

Comment: Yes. That is what I was doing but ran out of options. I checked the data, added null and '' handling, replaced characters that may interfere with the xml functions, made sure that when casting happens the same CCSIDs gets used and made sure that truncation of data will not happen. Normally there are a error code in the joblog that can be checked and referenced but in this case there are no specific code. I have reduced the functions input for XMLTEXT to the minimum and get the same error. It seems that XMLTEXT uses MapXmlData internally and that is giving the error....

Answer (score 0):

It is fine. I have modified the view to select both the header and detail, and search on both entity entries (linked on the key MSGOCCID) and do a DISTINCT on the key MSGOCCID. It seems a little bit slower than the view the question is about but is working fine. Thank you for you time.